# How to count the number of lines in php files?

Tags: php, windows, file-management

I am working on a php application and would like to know the number of lines in the files. The files are in a couple of different directories, but I can copy them all to one directory if needed.

What's the best Windows application/tool to count the number of lines in the files?

I've searched on here, but almost all of the questions were about counting in php, not using an external program.

Thank!

Comment: If you're using windows, I saw this tool:  http://thecodecentral.com/2007/12/26/source-line-of-code-counter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) is an extremely powerful tool that does what your asking and separates lines of code, blank lines and comments.

Comment: Neat, I've not seen this one before +1

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to a Linux shell, you can run this command:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec cat {} \; | wc -l
```

If you're on Windows, install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) first and then run the command.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I should have put Windows. I added that now. Thanks.

Comment: Useless abuse of `cat`... no need for it here. :)

Comment: That would fail where there are spaces or special chars in the filename. Better to use the -exec parameter of find, I think. ie: find . -type f -exec cat {} \; | wc -l

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `count(file($fn))` then external tools would also be feasible.

A standard Unix tool is `wc` wordcount. With the `-l` option just returns lines:

```
 $count = intval(`wc -l '$fn'`);
```

Don't forget escaping. And yes, you can google for a Windows version.

Comment: Doesn't this just count *any* line breaks in a file though ?

Comment: @RussC: how else would you define "new line"?

Comment: The OP was specifically talking about lines of code; this method whilst broadly accurate would also count multiline comments and XMLDoc style markup or anything *not actually php* as a line of code too.